# Layer Swipe implementation for TileLayer and WebGLTIleLayer

Tags: openlayers

OpenLayers currently has 2 examples on how to implement a layer swipe:
Classic Tile layers: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-swipe.html
WebGLTile layers: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-layer-swipe.html

I need to make it work for a mix of N Tile and WebGLTile layers.

When combining them, it seems like the WebGLTile layers are not cleared when cropped to a smaller area than the previous crop. This result in parts of the previous image to stay on top of a lower TileLayer:

[GIF of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i8OC.gif)

(Please don't mind the missing key image, it is just to show the behavior and I confirmed the same behavior with working layers).

**Reproduction:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-layer-swipe-broken-crrnvq?file=/main.js

In that sense, the WebGLTile layers are behaving differently than regular Tile layers that get erased properly even alone.

I tried calling `gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` in the 'prerender' callback is not a solution because it erases another WebGLTile layer below it that would be cropped on the other side of the swipe.

**Does someone know how to implement this cropping effect without relying on assumptions of the number of layers, the type of lower layers and so on?**

Comment: You could add a transparent WebGL layer immediately below the top layer https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-layer-swipe-broken-forked-zst11q

Comment: Thanks @Mike I didn't know you could do that, that works well.
For future reference, It also gave me the idea that it is actually possible to force a layer to be alone on a canvas by specifying a unique classname when creating the layer, and then it is possible to manually clear the canvas as it won't affect any other element.

Comment: For me `gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` was a solution, just call it before `gl.scissor()`